# Обновление страницы HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, база-данных, веб-программирование

Я создаю сайт, который включает себя динамический контент на странице. Нужно реализовать что-то вроде мини-админ панели, чтобы человек мог удалять некоторые данные с страницы.
Через JS сделано.

При  обновлении страницы естественно все изменения удаляются. Каким образом реализовать обновление не только страницы, но и самого html файла. Если делать это через php - нужно ли хранить код страницы в бд и обновлять его каждый раз при загрузке страницы? Или же можно это сделать с помощью запросов на js, не используя php

Answer (score 0):

Если речь про сохранение формы, то нужно на сервере сохранять информацию, а при загрузке страницы ее оттуда получать и на основе той информации строить/заполнять таблицу.

Если речь не про сохранение данных формы страницы.

Обновление страницы может происходить двумя способами: с полным сбросом состояния текущих полей или с заполнением страницы предыдущими данными. Тот или другой сценарии срабатывают в зависимости от нажатых кнопок.

В первом случае это нормальное поведение, а вот во втором, если на странице добавлялись или удалялись элементы, может быть не совсем нормальное.

Для этого нужно сохранить состояние полей страницы, например в браузере, при этом, эти данные должны быть привязаны к текущей странице и актуальны до перехода на любую другую страницу или сохранения или полного обновления страницы, иначе пользователь будет заходить на страницу и видеть неактуальные данные, т.е. те, которые он ввел последние раз.

При хранении информации нужно учитывать имена полей, потому что автоматическое восстановление данных происходит именно по старым именам. Конечно, если вы все храните в памяти (и данные и поля) и восстанавливаете эти данные оттуда, то об этом, возможно, не стоит думать.

Как хранить информацию в браузере: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage